# Single Page app using Controller - how to secure with ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze, single-page-application, asp.net-identity

I have a single page app that uses a standard Controller (not ApiController) for retrieving all HTML views, which is done via ajax.  However, WebApi is utilized using breezejs for the client to talk to the backend database. I am implementing ASP.NET identity security - should I use MVC cookie authentication or bearer token? I need the solution to illustrate a separate login page, and need a clean server side redirect.

Comment: If your WebAPI is handling security then what are you trying to accomplish with using the MVC Controller?  You want to secure your views from being opened?

Comment: Yes, I want to secure the site (views), and the web api.

Comment: How are you logging in?

Comment: Individual User Accounts using ASP.NET Identity database, but will authenticate against Yahoo, Facebook, etc. in the future.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer that I think should help you.  If it does not address your question directly please let me know.  I also updated your question to include the Breeze.js tag in case anyone else is looking for a similar answer in the future.

Answer (score 3):

#### Disclaimer

This is a relatively trivial question because it is very specific and by understanding the difference in authentication between Web API and MVC Controllers this should be fairly straight forward.

#### Assumptions

1. Your Web API Project has it's own authentication and does not talk to the MVC project to get a session user or anything
2. Your ASP.NET MVC Controllers are in a project using forms authentication and storing the user in a session cookie.
3. When I reference MVC below you undertand these are referencing ASP.NET MVC

#### Recommendation

What I would do is have your MVC project use OAuth for authentication and store the user in a cookie in the session that you can set and get.  Then your controller actions that serve views can be decorated with the Authorize attribute.  This will redirect users to the login page when they try to access a view they are not allowed to (as long as that is set up in your web.config

For the Web API Project you can't rely on Session because it sounds like you are decoupling the two projects.  This is my recommendation -

When your user is successfully authenticated in your MVC Project make a request to the Web API to an open log in method.  This would do some logical test and then either store the user in the DB with a session token of some sort or automatically write the user to the DB.

Now your user that is stored in session in your MVC project you can pass that down to the client and append it to the Breeze calls to your Web API and use that for authentication.  You will need to explicitly set up how long that token is for and such but it is pretty easy to append this to the Breeze.js call like such -

```
 var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('myService').withParameters({'tokenId': thisTokenId});
```

Now your queries will hit the API with a tokenId parameter that it can use for authentication.

**Edit**

If you want to set up your ASP.NET MVC Project to use OAuth you can following along with this link -

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Remember that forms based authentication just means (in a nutshell) that you will provide the user some way of logging in with a form of some sort.

Comment: When you say setup the login page in the config, are you talking about <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" name=".ACMFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>? Becuase I don't think I want forms authentication.  The new MVC identity example does this:app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });  And the SPA example utilizes a different form of security -

Comment: app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);  So, I was thinking I would need to UseOAuthBearerTokens to authenticate in both cases somehow.  I am thinking your suggestions are still correct, I just need to understand the login page redirect and how the web api side (breeze) will authenticate correctly

Comment: Added an edit to the bottom of the answer - forms authentication just means that you are providing a form for the user to use to log in, which in this case is probably a page allowing anonymous users to hit it.

Comment: PW I might need some clarification - I am not understanding passing the tokenId to breezejs.  What does breeze do with the token? I'm also not clear on the "request to the Web API to an open log in method. This would do some logical test and then either store the user in the DB with a session token of some sort or automatically write the user to the DB." So are you saying to have some back end breeze code to check the token on every breeze call?  Wouldn't just using bearer token auth for both just do the same thing without having to do this?